# Navigating between sections with Next & Previous

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simply

```
<section id="div_1">
 <a href="#">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="div_2">
 <a href="#">Next</a>
 <a href="#">Previous</a>
</section>

<section id="div_3">
 <a href="#">Previous</a>
</section>
```

I need simpy to navigate to these section when the `<a>` is clicked but cannot provide the `href="#"`value since that can be any value. I can not hard code the `id`. Simply just navigate to the section with the next `id` or previous `id`

Comment: I think you have to create a variable inside it on next and previous button you can save the index or the dynamic ID you have. Lastly, to enable and disable you can check with array length.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the class *navigate* to each link, and I've also added a data-direction attribute to each link. The class will let us add an event listener to all the links, and the data-direction attribute lets us know whether we should be moving forward or backwards. When a link is clicked, we find the parent section of that link, then find the next/previous sibling element, then scroll to it.

```
<section id="div_1">
    <a href="#" class="navigate" data-direction="next">Next</a>
</section>

<section id="div_2">
    <a href="#" class="navigate" data-direction="next">Next</a>
    <a href="#" class="navigate" data-direction="prev">Previous</a>
</section>

<section id="div_3">
    <a href="#" class="navigate" data-direction="prev">Previous</a>
</section>
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('.navigate').forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const currentSection = this.parentElement;
        let targetSection;

        if (this.dataset.direction === 'next') {
            targetSection = currentSection.nextElementSibling;
        } else if (this.dataset.direction === 'prev') {
            targetSection = currentSection.previousElementSibling;
        }

        if (targetSection) {
            targetSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    });
});
```